# how to check span class by capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

How to check how many `<span class=error>error text</span>` is on page?

The code below is not working:

```
should have_selector('span.error', :count => 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara):

```
all('a').each { |a| a[:href] }
```

So something like the following should be possible:

```
all('span.error').count.should == 5
```